# Evaluation of the integral of a linear gaussian model?

Tags: calculus, integration, normal-distribution

suppose the following $$P(x_1) \text{ ~ } N(7.3555\ ; 12.3433)$$ and $$P(x_2|x_1) \text{ ~ } N(0.995\ + \ 0.2351x_1\ ;13.732)$$
how to evaluate the following integral?

\begin{align*} \int \mathcal{I}_{x_2 \geq 20} p(x_1 | x_2)dP = & \int_{20}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(12.3433)}} \exp \left\{ - \frac{(x_1 - 7.3555)^2} {2(12.3433)} \right\} \\ & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(13.732)}} \exp \left\{ - \frac{(x_2 - (0.995 + 0.2351x_1))^2}{2(13.732)} \right\} dx_1 \, dx_2 \ \end{align*}

**EDIT**$$$$
The context of this question appeared while I was trying to understand more deeply how to infer in a hybrid bayesian network, there are several R packages that do that but I just wanted to get the math underlying it. the joint probability was easy to calculate for both the discrete case and the hybrid case to solve, but the marginals I couldn't solve it. the [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#The_integral_of_a_Gaussian_function) says
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  e^{-a(x+b)^2}\,dx= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}.$$
But I couldn't generalise it to the case of a linear gaussian where the mean is unknown and its just a linear combination of its continuous parents.

Comment: Welcome to Maths.SE ! You should provide more information about this question. In particular, it would very useful to know in which context this question appeared, what you know about the subject, what you have already tried and what are your ideas. Please read http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: [polar coordinates?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#By_polar_coordinates)

Comment: @Tom-Tom please see the updated question, I hope that's an enough elaboration.

Comment: Plug this to Wolfram alpha before trying here! That's a standard integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you use $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a x^2+b x+c} dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}+c}}{\sqrt{a}}$$ to reduce it to a single integral, after that $$\int_{A}^{\infty} e^{-a x^2+b x+c} dx =\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}+c} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{b-2 a A}{2
   \sqrt{a}}\right)+1\right)}{2 \sqrt{a}}$$ to compute the remaining integral

Comment: please excuse my ignorance...but what does exactly the capital "A" variable in the loss function refer to?

Comment: good point. corrected

Comment: alright so now I should substitute $A$ with 20 as my original problem stated..thank you for the generous help...but just out of curiousity what would be the case if $\infty$ was substituted with $B$ ?

Comment: difference of two such expressions: the one with A -> B and itself

Comment: I feel dumb right now